# Testing for statistical valididty

Tags: statistical-significance

"In Chile, where they typically dive alone, three of the six attacks since 1963 proved fatal," McCosker said. "Whereas, in California and Oregon, since 1950, only nine of 93 attacks were fatal."

The quote refers to white shark attacks on divers.  The claim is that these attacks tend to be fatal more often when divers go out alone (typical of Chile) rather than with companions (typical of California and Oregon).  Does this claim 
have statistical validity?

What statistical approach can I use to answer this question

Comment: What comprises an "attack" instance? If a group of 10 divers go out and the group encounters a shark, is that one attack or is it ten? If that's the case, it's like saying Russian Roulette is safer when playing with friends, which is true but conveys the wrong impression.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Fisher's Exact Test here.

```
           Fatal      Non-fatal           Total
Chile        3            3                 6
California   9            84            93
Total       12            87            99
```

Fisher's exact test: The two-tailed P value equals 0.0225.
The association between rows (groups) and columns (outcomes) is considered to be statistically significant.